# VPN connection between 2 sonicwall devices

Tags: vpn

I am trying to create a VPN connection between 2 sonicwall TZ 200 and I follow most popular tutorial on the net without success; as sonicwall - whatever I did - shows "No Active VPN Tunnels". The VPN should got linked between:

- Main Office [sonicwall router with local IP 192.168.2.1]
- Branch office [sonicwall router with local IP 192.168.3.1]

In both offices we have static WAN IP address from ISP.

I need to make basic Site to Site connection between those offices so they can access each other subnet.

What I need in order to make this work?

UPDATE:

the configuration I used is as following:
[image: General]
[image: Network]
[image: Branch office] [image: Main office]
[image: Proposals]
[image: Advance]

Then the it was activated like this from the other side but with changing the peer and local

[image: After activate]

UPDATE:

Aggressive mode:

1   11/08/2015 09:11:35.912 Info    VPN IKE IKE negotiation aborted due to timeout  192.168.1.15, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Tubli Office

2   11/08/2015 09:11:01.912 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Remote party timeout - Retransmitting IKE request.   192.168.1.15, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Tubli Office

3   11/08/2015 09:10:42.912 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Remote party timeout - Retransmitting IKE request.   192.168.1.15, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Tubli Office

4       11/08/2015 09:10:33.912 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Remote party timeout - Retransmitting IKE request.   192.168.1.15, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Tubli Office

5       11/08/2015 09:10:26.400 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Start Aggressive Mode negotiation (Phase 1)  192.168.1.15, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Tubli Office

---

Main mode:

1       11/08/2015 08:59:28.352 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Remote party timeout - Retransmitting IKE request.   192.168.1.20, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Main Office

2       11/08/2015 08:59:09.352 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Remote party timeout - Retransmitting IKE request.   192.168.1.20, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Main Office

3       11/08/2015 08:58:57.352 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Remote party timeout - Retransmitting IKE request.   192.168.1.20, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Main Office

4       11/08/2015 08:58:50.352 Info    VPN IKE IKE Initiator: Start Main Mode negotiation (Phase 1)    192.168.1.20, 500   xx.xx.xx.xxx, 500   VPN Policy: Main Office

I am sure settings are same from both sides. xx.xx.xx.xxx to hide the IP

Not sure if Advance settings is needed here as well but it is same in both sides

Comment: Please post the current VPN configs for each side so we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: @JimG. I have update the question with more details

Comment: We need to determine if the tunnel doesn't come up (problem in phase 1 or phase 2) or the tunnel goes up and you have a problem in other place (routing, rules, etc)

Please, pick in Log and paste all logs related to VPN categories.

Comment: Double check phase 1 and 2 settings on each device, they have to be identical. Try also to set phase 1 exchange mode to main instead of aggressive, as you are not using NAT-T.

Comment: Try to ping something on the other end of the tunnel, then post the log messages that show up when the tunnel tries to negotiate.  Also, while not the cause of the issue, I'd encourage you to use Main or IKEv2 mode instead of Aggressive mode, as @RobertoP indicated.

Comment: @KorXo the tunnel apparently doesn't coming up. I have updated the question with latest log events. -RobertoP I tried with both aggressive and main mode without success. -JimG I cannot ping anything from the other side it gives me timeout errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your last log, not even Phase 1 is established because both sides of tunnel got a timeout.

I would suggest to make a packet capture to find where the packet is stopping. You should filter in each device with public ip as filter. I suggest three scenarios:

- The (returning) traffic is dropped at the firewall. You will see a red line with a drop code.
- There are no returning traffic. Some device is dropping IKE packets in the middle.
- You see normal returning traffic. There are another problem in your tunnel config.

Comment: The problem resolved after enabling DMZ in WAN router.